# iOS 13 on iPod Touch 7th generation

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, ios

I develop mobile software. I have an **iPod Touch 7th generation (A2178)** which I need to update to iOS 13 in order to test a compatibility issue that some users have reported with an app. iOS 13 was released several days ago, and **Apple and all news sources report that the iPod Touch *7th generation* is compatible with iOS 13**. However, both the Software Update section of iOS and the iTunes app on my computer are telling me that the iPod is "up to date" with iOS 12.4.1

Does Apple use delayed rollouts for certain devices? Is there another way to update to iOS 13?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210327

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Source](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/):

> The supported device for iOS 13 as follows:
>
> - iPhone 11
> - iPhone 11 Pro
> - iPhone 11 Pro Max
> - iPhone XS
> - iPhone XS Max
> - iPhone XR
> - iPhone X
> - iPhone 8
> - iPhone 8 Plus
> - iPhone 7
> - iPhone 7 Plus
> - iPhone 6s
> - iPhone 6s Plus
> - iPhone SE
> - iPod touch (7th generation)**

But checking the fine print with `**` for the iPod touch states that it won’t be available on the iPod touch until the 24th or 25th of September (depending on your location).

Your best bet is probably to try installing a developer beta or a public beta.

Answer (score -2):

iPod Touch 7th generation is supported by iOS 13. Sometimes software update is slow to catch because of caching or similar behavior. Try restarting it and go to

`Settings -> General -> Software Update`

on the device, it should work.

In the picture you can see a restore image for an unreleased version being available for ipod touch 7th Gen

[image: Restore image]